# How do you copy rows in VBA and paste the row onto the end of another row?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a sheet that has policies placed on each row. What I'd like to do is search for policies that are tied to the same person and put them all on the same row. So, if there were two policies for John Smith then they would be on the same row after the sort.

The code included shows that I am first figuring out how many rows there are. I run a loop starting from the first row with entries (row 2) to the end of the sheet. For each of these rows, I store the first and last name of the person. Then I search the rows below that one inside of the nested for loop. If it finds that there is a match then it copies and pastes the row into the same row as the first instance of the name at the end of the first row. It then deletes the row that has been moved and decreases j by 1 to account for the fact that a row has been deleted.

It is hung up on the assignment of m inside of the if statement that is meant to determine how long the row is that will be pasted into. It then seems to have an issue with the copy and paste command that follows. (Probably because of the use of variables in the statements?)

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Sort()

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' This program sorts data by putting all of an    '
' insureds policies on the same row.              '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim wb As Workbook                       'used for the active workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet                  'name of the source sheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook                 'sets the active workbook
Set wsSrc = wb.Sheets("Policies")  'will be sheet being sorted

Dim i, j As Integer          'will be used as an index

'used to store the name of current insured for comparison
Dim firstname, lastname As String    

Dim n, m As Integer         'both are to be used for sizing of a sheet

' Determines how long the sheet is (length and width)
n = wsSrc.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
m = wsSrc.Range("2:2").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column


' Loop runs through the sheet row by row to find those 
' with the same name and then places these on the same row
For i = 2 To n

    firstname = wsSrc.Range("B" & i).Value   'assigns the current first name
    lastname = wsSrc.Range("A" & i).Value   'assigns the last name

    'searches the rows underneath the current row for duplicate names
    For j = i + 1 To n

        'finds duplicates
        If wsSrc.Range("B" & j).Value = firstname And wsSrc.Range("A" & j).Value = lastname Then
            m = wsSrc.Range("i:i").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
            'if true places the row at the end of the row that is the current insured.
            wsSrc.Range("A" & j).EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Cells(i, m + 1)
            'deletes the row that has been moved
            wsSrc.Rows(j).Delete
            'if true then a row is deleted and everything beneath it shifts up
            'to accomodate this we move j back by one and we need to reevaluate
            'length of the sheet
            n = wsSrc.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            j = j - 1


        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a specific command that I could use to just paste the portion of the row that has entries? That way I avoid pasting an entire row? It would be from column A to the last column with data in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy an entire row and paste it anywhere but in ColA - there's not enough room (and Excel doesn't care if most of the copied row is empty...)

You can avoid the nested loop, and resetting n and m, working from the bottom up, using something like this:

```
Sub Sort()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long         'will be used as an index
    Dim n, m As Long, mtch

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = wb.Sheets("Policies")

    ' Determines how long the sheet is (length and width)
    n = wsSrc.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    m = wsSrc.Range("2:2").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    For i = n To 2 Step -1
        'Find the first matching row based on First & Last names
        'https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/
        mtch = wsSrc.Evaluate("MATCH(A" & i & "&B" & i & ",A:A&B:B,0)")

        If mtch < i Then
            'matched row is above this one, so copy this row up and delete
            wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, m).Copy _
                wsSrc.Cells(mtch, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            wsSrc.Rows(i).Delete
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually neither of those allow me to do what I’m needing either. They both have an error

Comment: "an error" isn't very useful description of what happens when you run it.  Is it `wsDest` that's the problem?  That's in your code but maybe you meant `wsSrc` ?

Comment: It was displaying different errors depending on which version I tried. You are right though I did mean wsSrc.

Comment: The only thing it won't allow me to do is to determine the length of the row it is pasting into using the command m = wsSrc.Range("i:i").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column   It needs to know where to begin the pasting since the end of the row could be different depending on how many matches were already found and copy and pasted!

Comment: I removed the j=j-1 and it now pastes into the proper place with your updated pasting command! Thanks a load!

Comment: Except it only finds one match and stops! It won’t find third or fourth matches

Comment: Are you always copying the same number of columns (m) each time a row is moved, and is the next paste to that row always to start m columns from the last one?

Comment: Is every row full, or can there be empty cells on the end of the row?

Comment: Every row will have entries in every column until the end of the row

Comment: Rewrote my answer - I think there are some issues in your original code which are best avoided, and when deleting rows, working from the bottom-up is easier to manage.